# Get raw response headers from LWP?

Tags: perl, http-headers, lwp

Is there a way to grab raw, unmodified response headers from an HTTP request made with LWP?  This is for a diagnostic tool that needs to identify problems with possibly malformed headers.

The closest thing I've found is:

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
my $ua = new LWP::UserAgent;
my $response = $ua->get("http://somedomain.com");
print $response->headers()->as_string();
```

But this actually parses the headers, and then reconstructs a canonicalized, cleaned-up version of them from the parsed data.  I really need the entire header text in exactly the form in which it was returned by the server, so anything malformed or non-standard will be clearly identifiable.

If it turns out there is no way to do this with LWP, is there perhaps some other Perl module that can do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Net::HTTP](https://metacpan.org/module/Net::HTTP) provides lower level access with less processing.  Since it is a subclass of [IO::Socket::INET](https://metacpan.org/module/IO::Socket::INET) you can read directly from the object after making the request.

```
use Net::HTTP;

# Make the request using Net::HTTP.
my $s = Net::HTTP->new(Host => "www.perl.com") || die $@;
$s->write_request(GET => "/", 'User-Agent' => "Mozilla/5.0");

# Read the raw headers.
my @headers;
while(my $line = <$s>) {
    # Headers are done on a blank line.
    last unless $line =~ /\S/;
    push @headers, $line;
}
print @headers;
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on an inspection of the `HTTP::Response` object (and the `HTTP::Headers` object it contains), the headers are discarded as they're parsed.

I would recommend you try `WWW::Curl` instead.

**EDIT** Snippet using WWW::Curl:

```
use WWW::Curl::Easy;

my ($header, $body);

my $curl = WWW::Curl::Easy->new;
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_URL, $url_to_get); # get this URL
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER, \$header); # save header text in this var
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, \$body); # save body text in this var

my $code = $curl->perform;
if (0 == $code) {
  # header text is in $header, body text in $body 
} else {
  print $curl->strerror($code).": ".$curl->errbuf."\n";
}
```